# Which grammar framework the terms "predicate/ complement/ adjunct" belong to?

Tags: terminology, grammar, framework

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar#Grammar_frameworks), there're a number of grammar frameworks. Which framework the terms "predicate/ complement/ adjunct" belong to?

Comment: Most frameworks. They are old, pre-linguistics terms.

Comment: what would be linguistic terms instead?

Comment: @meireikei I think curiousdannii meant that they *are* linguistic terms, found in most frameworks, but that they derive from usages which predate modern linguistics.